# Trying to read json data into php variables to insert into mysql

Tags: php, json

I have a large amount of data in the following form that I have been trying to read into php variables which I will then use in my php code to upload to my mysql db. I am trying the following code to test on one section of the data but when I run the php page I just get a blank page instead of a print out of the data.

json data saved as books.json and in the root directory of my site

```html
﻿{
 "date_reviewed":"08/Jan/16",
 "fname":"John",
 "mname":"",
 "lname":"Locke",
 "email":"",
 "title":"Boxed In!",
 "imagelocation":"img\book_covers\BoxedIn.jpg",
 "series_name":"Dr. Gideon Box",
 "sellerssite":"https://www.amazon.com/Boxed-Gideon-Donovan-Creed-Novel-ebook/dp/B019HANKW8",
 "genre":"Thriller,Suspence",
 "authorsite":"https://johnlockeauthor.wordpress.com/",
 "facebook":"https://www.facebook.com/john.locke.395669?fref=ts",
 "fbid":"John Locke",
 "twitter":"https://twitter.com/DonovanCreed",
 "twitterid":"@DonovanCreed",
 "review":"A series you have to be sick to love. I guess that's telling as I do love the series.
                                The latest in a series from an author that also has a number of other series that I have been devouring for the last couple of years. What makes these series unique is that they are all tied together by the characters that star in each series. So, if you're a fan of one and have not branched out into the others then it is time to go to his author page and start the reading adventure that will take you into the minds of a lethal assassin, a gunfighter and reluctant sheriff, and a private detective made famous by escaping from a deranged kidnapper.
                                Dr. Box may be brilliant when it comes to saving the life of children written off as lost causes but his activities outside the operating room have left any that know him with a strong desire to see him thrown into the bowels of hell as he surely is the very epitome of demon walking the earth. Good thing that he's the only one in the world that can save a life that others deem impossible. Just pray that if you've ever slighted him that you never show up in his hospital under his care. It will be an encounter you never live to regret.
                                In this tale Dr. Box is visited by the only man that causes true fear in a doctor who's moral compass was broken at birth. Donovan Creed. An assassin that you do not want to owe a favor to.
                                Donovan comes to collect. He has the plan to kill a terrorist and in the process save thousands of lives. The only problem, what he wants is the one thing Dr. Box cannot do.
                                Painted into a box (pun intended) he has no choice but to call on the one person that even Donovan is afraid of. Rose.
                                Together they come up with a full proof plan. Too bad that Donovan is already two steps ahead and the consequences for Dr. Box are steep and his life may never be the same.
                                As a fan, I say you have to add this to your library.",
 "rating":"5"
}
```

PHP file

```html
<?php

   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array
   
   //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("books.json");

    // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
           
           print_r($arr_data)
?>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: After getting data from json try vat_dump($jsondata)

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad Asif, using var_dump I am able to at least know that the file is being read into the variable but it seems to be breaking when converting to an array? could there be escaping issue within the data?

Comment: After decoding json & storing in array, try "echo $arr_data['fname']"  or something similar

Comment: OK, looks like the $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true); is not working. I tried to echo the count of the array and it is empty.